# Переместить картинку из одного div элемента в другой

Tags: jquery, javascript

Не могу переместить картинки. Вернее могу, но перемещаются не все.

Из

```
<div id="poleGame" class="leftKart">
<img src="images/61.jpg">
<img class="left110" src="images/71.jpg" style="position: relative;">
<img src="images/63.jpg">
</div>
```

картинки хочу переместить в

```
<div id="karts"> </div>
```

Для этого использую следующий код

```
for (i = 0; i < $('#poleGame img').length; i++) {
    $('#karts').append($('#poleGame img').eq(i));
}
```

И вот эта картинка не перемещается

```
<img class="left110" src="images/71.jpg" style="position: relative;">
```

Comment: @Радик Камалов, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

лучше применить нечто подобное:

`$(function(){
   $('#poleGame img').clone().appendTo($('#karts'));
   $('#poleGame img').remove();
});`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var karts = $('#karts');
    $('poleGame img').each(function(){
        karts.append($(this).remove());
    });
});
```

по идее так, сам не проверял, если что - пиши